# TypeError: f() argument after * must be an iterable, not float

Tags: python, numpy, ode

i am working on a code for a free fall object using ODE and i am not sure what it says or how to fix it.
it tells "TypeError: f() argument after * must be an iterable, not float". thank you

```
import numpy as np
import scipy.integrate as spi
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import solve_ivp


m = 63974.  # particle's mass in kg
k = 12.  # drag coefficient
g = 9.81  # gravity acceleration

# The initial position is (0, 0).
v0 = np.zeros(4)
v0[1] = 1668. 
v0[3] = 98. 


def f(v, t0, k,):
    
    # v has four components: v=[u, u'].
    u, udot = v[:2], v[2:]
    # We compute the second derivative u'' of u.
    udotdot = (-k / m) * np.power(udot,2) 
    udotdot[1] -= g
    # We return v'=[u', u''].
    return np.r_[udot, udotdot]

def stop_condition(t,v0):
    return v0[0]

stop_condition.terminal = True
stop_condition.direction = -1
t = np.linspace(0., 40., 100,)
t_span = (0,40)

sol = solve_ivp(f, v0, t_span,args=k, events=stop_condition)

print(sol.t_events)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with ODE, but the error suggests that the parameter for `args` in `solve_ifp` must be iterable. Thus, try `args=[k]`.

Comment: And remove the trailing comma in `def f`.

Comment: already chance args=[k] and remove comma in def f. but the outout tells TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable

Comment: So the original error is corrected. Now you get the next error, you are using a variable as vector that in truth is only a scalar. This frequently happens when arguments are switched. One way to avoid that is to always use the order (t,y) and give the option `tfirst=True` to odeint. (Which adds overhead to the already existing overhead, but if you want efficiency you would be using a compiled language with a strategy for a drastically reduced number of vector allocations.)

Answer (score 2):

Once again, need to remind you that I'm not familiar with ODE. But I've read the documentation for [`scipy.intergrate.solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) and found some logical errors in your code.

### 1. First error `TypeError: f() argument after * must be an iterable, not float`

Because in your `solve_ivp` function your parameter for `args=k`, this suggests that `k` will be passed to your `f` function. Thus you need to change it to `[k]`.

```
# sol = solve_ivp(f, v0, t_span,args=k, events=stop_condition) # your code
sol = solve_ivp(f, v0, t_span,args=[k], events=stop_condition)
```

After implementing this, a different error is raised.

```
<ipython-input-38-1a7549e0840c> in f(v, t0, k)
     20 def f(v, t0, k,):
     21     # v has four components: v=[u, u'].
---> 22     u, udot = v[:2], v[2:]
     23     # We compute the second derivative u'' of u.
     24     udotdot = (-k / m) * np.power(udot,2)

TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

This tells me that there is an error on your `v` argument in your `f` function.

### 2. Second error, fixing the `fun` parameter.

Reading through the documentation for [`scipy.intergrate.solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) suggest that the first positional argument of `solve_ivp` is `fun` which is callable and you correctly placed `f`, a callable as your `fun`. But the documentation also says that the positional arguments in `fun` are `t,y` (`fun(t,y)`). Assuming that `v` is your `y`, then you placed them the other way around.

```
# def f(v, t0, k,): # this is yours
def f(t0, v, k):
```

Now the previous error is fixed, but another error is raised.

```
<ipython-input-41-b0878a24d79f> in f(t0, v, k)
     23     # We compute the second derivative u'' of u.
     24     udotdot = (-k / m) * np.power(udot,2)
---> 25     udotdot[1] -= g
     26     # We return v'=[u', u''].
     27     return np.r_[udot, udotdot]

IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

This tells me that `udotdot`'s length is less than 2. Reading your code carefully, I noticed that `udotdot` should've been half of `v` which is an array of length 4. So, I checked by simply printing out `v` in your function.

```
def f(t0, v, k): 
    print('t:', t0)
    print('v:', v)
```

Output:

```
t: 0.0
v: [ 0. 40.]
```

After seeing this I noticed that the `v` is incorrect. It should've been `[0, 1668, 0, 98]`

### 3. Error with `v0` and `t_span` positional argument in `solve_ivp`.

After reading the documentation for [`scipy.intergrate.solve_ivp`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.solve_ivp.html) once again, I noticed that the positional arguments of `v0` and `t_span` in your code should be switched.

```
# sol = solve_ivp(f, v0, t_span,args=[k], events=stop_condition) # the code so far
sol = solve_ivp(f, t_span, v0, args=[k], events=stop_condition)
```

After doing this the a new error is raised.

```
TypeError: stop_condition() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

Unlike your previous error, this one is very clear. Because your `f` accepts 3 parameters, your `stop_condition` should also accept 3 parameters as well.

### 4. Updating `stop_condition()`

```
# def stop_condition(t, v0): # your code
def stop_condition(t, v0, k):
    return v0[0]
```

By fixing those lines, your code should work fine. However, I'm not sure if the final output is equal to your desired output (Once again, I'm not familiar with ODE).

### Bonus

You can use `*args` and `*kwargs` instead of `k` for your `f()` and `stop_condition()` functions. I'm not going to explain them in details. Please read [this article](https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/) if you want to learn how to use them.